# SwiftyJSON - var searchIndex: Index! Error Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, algolia

Every time I import SwiftyJSON into my project. It throws an error with Index! Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using this with Algolia search.

**Error Message:** Reference of type general

asks me to insert < Any>! then once inserted asks me to remove it.

*Index!* - isn't a general, though. It's used with the Algolia cocoa pod.

```
class SearchVC: UITableViewController {

var businessSearch = [Business]()

// Where the problem occurs
var businessIndex: Index!

let query = Query()
var searchId = 0
var displayedSearchId = -1
var loadedPage: UInt = 0
var nbPages: UInt = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftyJSON and AlgoliaSearch both use ***Index***

So in order to specify which module you want to use, you need to put: ***AlgoliaSearch.Index!***